# XCode, standard C++ and ifstream file handling

Tags: c++, xcode, file-io

Recently, I figured out that Xcode could be used to write normal C++ programs.

My problem is with the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char operation='0';
    int operand=0;
    //open file for reading  
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open (argv[1]);
    if(!ifile.is_open()){
            cout<<"Invalid file\n";
            exit(1);
    }
    while(ifile.good())
    {
            ifile>>operation;

            if(operation=='I') {  
                    ifile>>operand;
                    cout<<"Inserting :"<<operand<<endl;
                                                    }
            else
            if(operation=='D') { cout<<"Deleting  "<<endl;
                                                    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When the input is the following ,

```
I 4
I 8
I 10
I 9
*
```

When I compile and run in Xcode , I get the following

```
Loading program into debugger…
Program loaded.
run
[Switching to process 58116]
Inserting :0
Running…

Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:0.
```

I have set the filename as an argument in the project preferences.

However, in the Terminal , I get

```
Inserting :4
Inserting :8
Inserting :10
Inserting :9
```

Please help me understand why this happens.

Comment: What's the problem?  It looks like it's working just fine.  What were you expecting that you didn't see.

Comment: @Stabledog: The debugger output shows `Inserting :0` and nothing else.

Comment: Just an observation unrelated to the problem: instead of `ifile.good()` you should use just `ifile` (with implicit conversion to `bool`) or `!ifile.fail()`. Iostreams `good` is not the opposite of `fail`... Re the problem, perhaps if you stop the program at the very end you'll see all the output?

Comment: How are you specifying the arguments argv[1]? Specifically what is the value of 'argv[1]' and are you sure you are opening up the right file?

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach using `ifile` or `ifile,fail()` results in the same behavior.

Comment: Also, the same program without any modification compiles and runs fine if I use Terminal, so I think that it is specific to the way Xcode invokes 'gcc' , etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not figure out what it was, but reinstalling XCode solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify an absolute path in your project preferences argument.

Comment: That's just asking for trouble… if the file is in the project directory, its path should be project-relative.

Answer (score 0):

First as a standard rule when debugging. **Eliminate all unnecessary complexity**

I suspect your problem is that you are not correctly specifying `argv[1]` in your debugging parameters, but I could be wrong.

First, try manually specifying the filename rather than accepting it from argv[1]. (The relative path should be from your 'project/build/Debug' directory)

You need to check ifile.good() **after** you attempt to read the byte, only then would you know if **EOF** was hit while reading.

Lastly, always check **argc** when reading **argv[]**.

Comment: I removed the check of _argc_ when posting here. The file path is _/ads/test.txt_ , and is output correctly by `cout<<argv[1]` . In addition, the first `I` is read , resulting in `Inserting :0` output, so I think that the file  is open. Anyways, I just passed the filename instead of `argv[1]` and get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Edit Active Executable" to access the settings for working directory and command-line arguments.

XCode unfortunately has a few redundant project settings, and you need to open the right window.

Comment: Yes, I have put it right there , hardcoding the filename does not work either.